# echo a True conditional statement out of many in php

Tags: php

I have an array.

```
if (        $date_month == $months['1'] ||
            $date_month == $months['2'] ||
            $date_month == $months['3'] ||
            $date_month == $months['4'] ||
            $date_month == $months['5'] ||
            $date_month == $months['6'] ||
            $date_month == $months['7'] ||
            $date_month == $months['8'] ||
            $date_month == $months['9'] ||
            $date_month == $months['10'] ||
            $date_month == $months['11'] ||
            $date_month == $months['12'] 
            ) {
            echo "its true";


        }else{
            echo "its false";
        }
```

I want to echo the value of the one thats true.  Currently I have to write if statements for each.  Was wondering if there was a way to just echo which ever on is true in the conditional.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For example - You want to echo that month 7 is the true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the PHP function: `in_array()`:

```
if (in_array($month, $month_array)){

  echo "Found";

}else{

  echo "Not Found";

}
```

Or you could do:

```
if( $month_array[$month]){

   echo "true";

}else{

   echo "false";

}
```